# CakePHP Default Bake Paths :: Can they be changed?

Tags: cakephp, schema, cakephp-bake

I recently downloaded a Cake site from a live server, and I am trying to bake some aspects. But I am getting files not found errors (even though they do exist), but the structure is different that the out-of-box CakePHP download. So I am wondering if I am missing the point on all this, or there is a simple way to adjust what the CLI looks for in terms of paths - namely the config/ for an ACL schema is what I am trying to crunch out.. Thanks for any advice. Been at this for a while now.

Comment: The app is up and running locally and of course my core is mapped properly in my index.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could have been doing something totally zombie-like, but I decided just to re-bake and copy my original MVC files to the new baked folders (used the new config schema folder), but the issue is now resolved by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck looking at the paths.php config file. It's in /cake/config/paths.php . I'm not positive how it works but it might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did the below and solved the issue w/out getting into the core files : ) - I try to stay away from those at all cost!

Answer (score 0):

**Idea 1:**

Perhaps this is too simple, but are you sure you are running bake correctly? You should setup a environment variable for bake, orrr type the full path of bake while you are in your app folder. There are more details here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1106/The-CakePHP-Console

Note:

> $    cd /my/cake/app_folder
>   $    ../cake/console/cake

That will open up your cake prompt and should also resolve missing paths.

**Idea 2:**
Missing paths in cake can also occur as a result of non-conventional filenames, classnames etc... even if your app is working other things may not like testing, tasks, or bake. Example: in plugins if you actually follow the standard and append model to the class name, you need to then have $uses in your controller. Testing also brakes as a result if everything isn't defined.

**Idea 3:**
I have changed the path for my cake location before in app/index.php and app/webroot/test.php  perhaps you could do the same for bake in one of those files, but since it is in cake/console you may need to do it from somewhere in that folder. Before you modify they cake folder, I would make sure to fork cake, so that you can easily still pull updates without over writing your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I solved the issue by doing a re-bake and copying the "old" MVC files to my fresh bake and all was resolved.